# c# dateTimePicker хранить дату в базе Mysql

Tags: c#

при добавлении в базу данных Date time возникает ошибка, может неправильно конвертирую дату. ниже выложил скрин ошибки и код. помогите пожалуйста разобраться. тип данных в Mysql datetime

```
private void Addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        try { 

        string query = "insert into sta(name, year, prefix, size, freesize, dates) Values (@name, @year, @prefix, @size, @freesize, @dates)";
           
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = AutoNumberedTable(dt);
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
       
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = comboBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prefix", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@freesize", MySqlDbType.Int32, 20).Value = textBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dates", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text);
           
            
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Added!");
        }

        con.Close();


        spisok();
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
            con.Close();
        }
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте без преобразования dateTimePicker1.Value

Comment: можно подробнее ?,  '" + dateTimePicker.Text+ "' ?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@dates", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;

Comment: не работает , такая же ошибка.  может как-то нужно настроить сам контроллер dateTimePicker ?

Comment: покажите таблицу sta что не понятно какие у вас там поля какого типа

Comment: добавил изображение

Comment: а всю таблицу нет

Comment: просто у вас там требуется тип интежер а вы подаёте туда строку, не понятно почему

Comment: выложил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: переведите строки в интежер тогда, на size, freesize

Comment: причем там строки ? строки прекрасно хранятся в базе данных , там не числовые значения а смешанные ,  без dateTimePicker все данные вставляются, с добавлением dateTimePicker возникает эта ошибка